# Почему размер модераторской очереди не сходится?

Tags: дефект, поддержка, инструменты-модератора

Довольно часто не совпадает число на значке с реальным количеством тревог:
Often enough the icon does not match the real number of the flags:

[image: скриншот/screenshot]

Comment: Скорее всего, это кэш. Наверное надо канонический вопрос писать с кучей ситуаций движка SO, которые подвержены эффекту кэша.

Comment: @alexolut, на иконке не сходится, в заголовке вроде как раз верно.

Comment: правильно 5 тревог?

Comment: @alexolut, не помню, они уже закончились. Но обычно именно на иконке было неправильно.